# How to determine if the subprocess has end processing?

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans

I'm currently working with Netbeans and calling Matlab functions from Netbeans interface. Does anybody know how to determine when the Matlab process has done processing and prompt Netbeans that it is done processing?

i've tried the following code:

```
System.out.println(p.getInputStream().read());
```

because as what I have read it will return -1 if the process ends, but it returns -1 even before the process starts.

I hope someone could help me. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If p is the Process object that represents the matlab process, you should be able to call p.waitFor() which will block until the sub-process ends. When the sub-process does end, it returns an int that is the return value of the process (usually zero means success.)

Comment: yes sir, p is process. And I did what you say; to put p.waitFor() but still it returns 0 before the matlab opens. Thank you for your quick response

Comment: is it possible if i will read a return statement from matlab to netbeans? so i could just add an ending statement in matlab that returns statement?thanks again